# Creating (complex?) doc/pdf document with java - what is the nicest way?

Tags: java, templates, pdf, doc

we need to create a pdf or doc document contaning some portion of model data. Each model object contains single values, plus few collections of related data, they are of various length. Now, some portions of the model data can be disabled, so that they should not be included in the final document. I need a clever way to creating a document using only selected parts of model data, and I don't wont to run into mess like:

```
if (DATA_TITLE is selected)
   add DATA_TITLE to document
if (DATA_AUTHOR is selected)
   add DATA_TITLE to document
etc..
```

How can I avoid this in a elegant way?

And the other thing: at the moment I wanted to create the document "programatically", using for example Apache POI lib. But, maybe there is some other way, where I can use document templates and fill the data wit EL expressions, thus with using ${data.author} fields withing the template. But then, how to manage the fact, that not all the data elements may be selected for document export, and that collections of related data may be of various length.

I need your precious knowledge :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use XSL-FO transformations if you don't want to do it programmatically.

I'd still recommend iText.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, I would use the Observer design pattern to update a document model only when the affected fields are changed programmatically.

For your second question, if you used a document model with an observer, you could simply create a default implementation for your fields which would only be changed through events that you code into your observer.

Check out the pattern: [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: I'm not really sure where should I stick the patter to. I'm actually not sure if we understand ourselves correct. At the model data is a collection of Books. These books have various data describing them, like author, title etc. The user selects thru web interface which parts of books description should be included in the exported document. At the moment, I have a sorted list of all books and I can check with `book.hasPart(PART_NAME)` if the book description part was selected. Now I need to put all this data into a pdf or doc document :) So, is your TIP with the Observer Pattern still valid?

Comment: I would add an observer to your code that listens for the user selecting what should be included. When selected/deselected, the observer could find the book in question (a Map implementation collection might be best here) and update the variables accordingly.